# How to dynamically allocate a single int[10] object?

Tags: c++

Obviously this won't work, because it's interpreted as allocating an array of `int`:

```
int (*ptr)[10] = new int[10];
```

Surprisingly, this doesn't work either:

```
typedef int arr10[10];
arr10 *ptr = new arr10;
```

This does work:

```
ptr = new int[1][10];
```

but it uses `new[]` rather than `new`.

For my own curiosity, is it possible to use `new` to allocate a single object of type `int[10]`, rather than using `new[]` to allocate an array of 10 objects, or an array of one `int[10]` object?

Comment: wtf are you doing and most importantly, why?

Comment: What exactly do you need? 10 integers? What's wrong with `new int[10];`?

Comment: And what might be the reason for allocating an array with `new` instead of `new[]`?

Comment: This is an interesting question because it is an attempt to understand the nature of arrays. The OP is obviously not trying to use this for practical purposes but is asking out of interest. Suggestions to use `std::vector` or `std::array` thus seem misplaced.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Suggestions to use `std::vector` or `std::array` are *never* misplaced, but I see where you are coming from. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. Arrays in C++ do not have first-class object semantics, for example they cannot be passed to functions* or returned from functions.

You can use std::array in C++11. It has many advantages: object semantics, index checks in debug mode, iterator and STL interface, `size()` method, no implicit conversion to pointers. When you have access to a C++11 compiler, there's almost no reason to use plain old C arrays anymore.

---

* It is only possible to pass pointers to elements or pointers/references to the array.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I can assure you, your answer is anything but trivial.

Answer (score 3):

One way, working <sup>1</sup>within the imperfect type system rules:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    using Ten_ints = int [10];
    Ten_ints* p_ints = []() -> Ten_ints*
    {
        struct Wrapper{ Ten_ints a; };
        return &(new Wrapper)->a;
    }();
    (void) p_ints;
}
```

A more direct way, taking charge of things:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    using Ten_ints = int [10];
    Ten_ints* p_ints = reinterpret_cast<Ten_ints*>( new Ten_ints );
    (void) p_ints;
}
```

The first snippet does what the OP asked (quoted at the end of this answer), using plain `new` instead of `new[]` to allocate the object. The second snippet shows the IMO most natural way to use `new[]` instead. The OP's suggestion of `new int[1][10]` is a second way to do that (and is thus a third way to obtain the pointer to array), and has the advantage of working within the type system, but the drawback that it's not very obvious.

In conclusion, the answer to

> **”** is it possible to use [non-array] `new` to allocate a single object of type `int[10]`

is, of course.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The standard guarantees that there's no padding at the start of a POD `struct`. In practice that means that deallocation is no problem either. But for the formal one would need to use the same type for deallocation as for allocation.</sup>

Comment: `auto main() -> int` makes me sad...  Maybe I'm just an old curmudgeon, but I don't see how adding lambdas, unneeded trailing return types and random structs helps explain a basic question about creating an array with `new`.  How is someone that can't use 'new' properly expected to understand any of this?

Comment: @JPhi1618: You comment is very emotional and baffling, but I'll try to reflect back what I get out of it. I think your comment is about that evolution of the C++ language, or perhaps any language, makes you "sad". Maybe you once learned `int main`, and now you have to deal with a different syntax, and that makes you sad. Apparently you feel that most others also find it difficult to adjust. Yes?

Comment: @JPhi1618: Anyway, could you elaborate on what you mean by "random structs"? There is nothing random about any of the code presented in this answer. I am therefore at a loss as to what that *could* mean.

Comment: I just don't understand why you would use so much code when the OP just had a basic question about how to use new.  I don't know what question you were answering and how creating a lambda function that wraps a local variable in a struct just so you can call new on the struct is solving anything.  This was a beginner question, and you seem to have tried to solve it in the most complex way possible.  And 'sad' was joking - I shouldn't have added any frivolity to the comment.

Comment: Plus this is almost identical to the `typedef int arr10[10];` solution the OP listed, except that it serves as a mini-menagerie of "Modern C++" features.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Oh. You could just have asked, you know. The first snippet does what the OP asked (quoted at the end of this answer), using plain `new` instead of `new[]` to allocate the object, and it's the only code presented in the answers here, that does it. The second snippet shows the IMO most natural way to use `new[]` instead. The OP's suggestion of `new int[1][10]` is a second way to do that, and has the advantage of working within the type system, but the drawback that it's not very obvious.

Comment: @Grault: re your comment that "this is almost identical to the typedef int arr10[10]; solution the OP listed", that's **meaningless**, I'm sorry. I do not know what misconception lies behind that statement, but it's meaningless. I.e. it has no meaning, it's techno-babble.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Thanks for pointing out the un-clarity; I'm adding the explanation to the answer.

Comment: @JPhi1618: The problem is that I don't know how to use `new`; the problem is that I wanted to know if `new` can be used to allocate an object of array type. (as opposed to, for example, `new[]` being used to allocate an array of objects of some type)...

Comment: ... and @Grault: the `typedef` solution *doesn't* work, because the expression `new arr10` does **not** invoke `operator new` for the type `arr10`, but instead `operator new[]` for the type `int`.

Comment: @Hurkyl: The answer you have selected as solution starts with "This is not possible", which is patently false. Maybe none of the answers here are really good enough. But it would be nice if you would undo that choice, if possible, since it misleads all readers who come here e.g. via Google.

Comment: @Cheers: IMO, your answer does not answer the question I asked. I haven't downvoted since I think it's a fair observation to a *related* question, but it would be misleading to imply in any way that it is a demonstration that what I actually asked is possible.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Then your question is just too vague. It seems now you're asking if there's any way to make `new int[10]` do something else than it does without adding anything to the mix. That's a meaningless question, so what are your permissible ways? Anything that works, is not permissible? The basic way in C++ to allocate a raw array with plain `new`, is to have it in a `struct`.

Comment: For non-onanistic way see @CaptainWise(@-3mins from your paroxysm)

Answer (score 2):

You **are** allocating an array of objects.

`T[10]` is 10 objects, not one. Actually, it's *eleven* objects -- an array (type `array of 10 T`), containing 10 `T` objects.

This requires constructor calls for each `T`, and corresponding destructor calls when the array gets `delete`d, which is why `new[]` and `delete[]` are necessary for arrays, and **if you try to work around that, your code will be broken.**

So:

```
int * ptr = new int[10];

// ...

delete [] ptr;
```

Or [Boost it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) (because naked pointers are ugly and error-prone):

```
boost::shared_array< int > ptr( new int[10] );

// ...
```

Or (because not everyone likes Boost, and the standard has brought us [the `<array>` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array< int, 10 > a;

// ...
```

Or the old standby, [`<vector>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector< int > v( 10 );

// ...
```

Comment: @thab: Correct. Ad-libbed the `std::shared_ptr` usage (still chained to the pre-C++11 ball and `boost::shared_array` here) and got it completely bass-ackwards.

Comment: I think it is important to differentiate between arrays represented by the _C++ type_ `T[size]`, and the concept of arrays as a _contiguous data structure_, as it can be found within `std::vector`, memory allocated by `std::malloc()` or `new[]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` operator allocate memory for one element of a type. It's the way it works. If you want to allocate a sequence of more than one element you need to use the array operator and specify the number of the element you want `new int[5]`. If you realy want to do something like that you can define a struct and set a array on it. So after that when you call new, this will allocate the array himself.

```
typedef struct TEST{
    int testInt[5];
};

TEST* myVarTest = new TEST();
```

Answer (score 2):

`new int[10]` *does* allocate a single object of type `int[10]`, that is, an array of 10 `int`s. The return value of the expression is a pointer to the first element of this array, though. Quoting C++14, 5.3.4/5:

> When the allocated object is an array (that is, the *noptr-new-declarator syntax* is used or the *new-type-id* or
>   *type-id* denotes an array type), the *new-expression* yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array.
>   [ *Note:* both `new int` and `new int[10]` have type `int*` and the type of new `int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]`
>   *—end note* ]